# Вывести массив в label

Tags: delphi

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
var
  m: array [1..n] of integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to n do
    label1.capton : = m[i];
end;
```

Как мне вывести весь массив `m` в один label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

эээ...

```
for i := 1 to n do 
  label1.caption := label1.caption + ' ' + m[i];
```

Не катит?

Comment: я бы немного поправил :)
for i := 1 to n do 
begin
label1.caption := label1.caption+IntToStr(m[i])+ #10+#13;
end

Comment: Да, спасибо. Уже относительно давно на Delphi не пишу, подзабыл кое-что... 
Кстати, а зачем вставлять символ переноса строки? По-моему, пробел нормально тоже будет...

Comment: да просто что бы не в одну строку, но кому как предпочтительнее :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var
  m: array [1..n] of integer;
  s: string;
begin
  for i := 1 to n do
    m[i] := i;

  for i := 1 to n do
    s := s + IntToStr(m[i]) + ' ';

  label1.caption := s;
end;
```

Comment: Поправте формат кода.